# Windows Forms form doesn't update text label with data incoming from another file

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms

I'm trying to make a Windows form server application, but for some reason when server (which is on another file) pass any data to form file, the text label on form does not update.

**Server file**

```
class Server {
        private TcpListener _serverSocket;
        private TcpClient _clientSocket;

        frm_MainScreen mainScreen = new frm_MainScreen();
        
        public Server(int port) {
            _serverSocket = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, port);
        }

        public void StartServer() {
            try {
                _serverSocket.Start();
                mainScreen.AddDeviceEntry("SERVER", _serverSocket.Server.LocalEndPoint.ToString());
            } catch (SocketException e) {
                mainScreen.ShowMessageBox("Ocorreu um erro", e.Message);
            }
        }
    }
```

**Form file**

```
public partial class frm_MainScreen : Form {
        public frm_MainScreen() {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void frm_MainScreen_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
            Server server = new Server(8600);
            Thread serverThread = new Thread(server.StartServer);
            serverThread.Start();
        }

        public void ShowMessageBox(string title, string msg) {
            MessageBox.Show(msg, title, MessageBoxButtons.OK);
        }

        public void AddDeviceEntry(string device, string ipAndPort, string status = "offline") {
            switch (device) {
                case "SERVER":
                    string[] infoField = ipAndPort.Split(':');
                    lblB_ServerIP.Text = infoField[0];
                    lblB_ServerPort.Text = infoField[1];
                    lblB_ServerIP.Refresh();
                    lblB_ServerPort.Refresh();
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Any error messages? Did you try setting breakpoints and see if your methods are being called?

Comment: `frm_MainScreen mainScreen = new frm_MainScreen();` this is not the Form that created your Server instance, it's a new Form instance you just created locally. Pass the current instance of `frm_MainScreen` to the Server object when you initialize it. Or pass an `IProgress<T>` object which can be used to update your UI from a different thread.